# How to calculate accurate distance travelled by the user using google maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, fusedlocationproviderapi

I am having two doubts because today only i started doing projects on google maps my first doubt is

1. How to calculate distance traveled by user when using google maps ?

like how taxi app is calculating the distance, now let me explain my problem in depth regarding this question i have checkin and check out button in map when user click the checkin button i will take that exact lat and long of that user when user checkout i will fetch the lat and long from where he checked out, after i will send this source latlong and destination latlong to google api this will return the kilometer. But what i need is wherever he traveled he may traveled extra bit of kilometer i need to calculate that also how can i do that.

2. My second doubt is my google maps taking long time to plot the blue mark  in my map it shows searching for gps in notification bar how can i achieve this ?

**Below is my complete Code**

> VisitTravel.java

```
public class VisitTravel extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
  GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
  LocationListener {
    private List < LatLng > obj;
    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    private Double latitue, longtitue, Start_lat, Start_long;
    private SupportMapFragment mapFrag;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Location mLastLocation;
    private ImageView cancel_bottomsheet;
    protected static final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 0x1;

    private Bundle bundle;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private String Checkin, parsedDistance, duration, JsonResponse;
    private VisitDAO visitDAO;
    private Long primaryID;
    private ArrayList < LatLng > points;
    private Integer id, flag, incidentid, userid;
    private TextView heading, duration_textview, dot_source, destination, distance;
    private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;
    private BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_visit_travel);
      // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
      mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
      mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);
      InternetCheck internetCheck = new InternetCheck();
      boolean check = internetCheck.isNetworkAvailable(VisitTravel.this);
      if (!check) {
        showAlertDialog();
      } else {
        createLocationRequest();
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        Settingsapi();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(VisitTravel.this);
        //  polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
        cancel_bottomsheet = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        heading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.heading);
        dot_source = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dot_source);
        distance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.distance);
        duration_textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.duration);
        destination = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.destination);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Fetching Location Updates");
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressDialog.show();
        View bottomSheet = findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);
        LoginDAO loginobj = new LoginDAO(this);
        userid = loginobj.getUserID();
        bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
        bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
        cancel_bottomsheet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {
            bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
          }
        });
        bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
          flag = bundle.getInt("flag");
          latitue = bundle.getDouble("destination_lat");
          longtitue = bundle.getDouble("destination_long");
          incidentid = bundle.getInt("incidentid");
          if (flag == 1) {

          } else {
            //  time = bundle.getString("checkin");
            id = bundle.getInt("id");
            incidentid = bundle.getInt("incidentid");
            Start_lat = bundle.getDouble("lat");
            Checkin = bundle.getString("checkin");
            Start_long = bundle.getDouble("long");
            String address = bundle.getString("startaddress");
            String distance = bundle.getString("estimateddistance");
            setBottomSheet(address, distance);
          }
        }
        obj = new ArrayList < > ();
        final FloatingActionButton startfab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.start);
        final FloatingActionButton stopfab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.stopfab);
        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
          "WakelockTag");
        wakeLock.acquire();
        visitDAO = new VisitDAO(getApplicationContext());
        if (flag == 2) {
          startfab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        startfab.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_black_24dp);
        final SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("lat_long", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        startfab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
              if (mLastLocation != null) {
                String checkin_to_server = dateFormat.format(new Date());
                Date date = null;
                try {
                  date = dateFormat.parse(checkin_to_server);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                }

                String checkin_view = dateview.format(date);
                double startinglat = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
                double startinglong = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
                //        String addres=address(startinglat,startinglong);
                String jsonresponse = null;
                try {
                  jsonresponse = new GetDistance().execute(startinglat, startinglong, 12.951601, 80.184641).get();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                }
                ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();
                if (jsonresponse != null) {
                  Log.d("responsejson", jsonresponse);
                  parserTask.execute(jsonresponse);
                }
                JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                try {
                  jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonresponse);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                }

                //Here il save the userlocation in db
              } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
            } else {
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Wait Till We Recieve Location Updates", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

          }
        });
      stopfab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          if (mLastLocation != null) {
            double lat = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
            double longt = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
            String startlat = preferences.getString("startlat", "");
            Log.d("startlat", startlat);
            String startlong = preferences.getString("startlong", "");
            // Calculating distance
            String distance = getKilometer(Double.valueOf(startlat), Double.valueOf(startlong), lat, longt);
            Intent intent = new Intent(VisitTravel.this, IncidentView.class);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
          } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Wait Fetching Location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }

@Override
public void onStart() {
  super.onStart();
  Log.d("start", "onStart fired ..............");
  mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

private void showAlertDialog() {
  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(VisitTravel.this);
  builder.setTitle("Network Connectivity")
    .setMessage("Please Check Your Network Connectivity")
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), IncidentView.class);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
      }
    });
  AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
  alert.show();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
  //  progressDialog.dismiss();
  if (wakeLock.isHeld()) {
    wakeLock.release();
  }
  //stop location updates when Activity is no longer active
  if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
  }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
  mGoogleMap = googleMap;
  mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
  map_marker_End(12.951601, 80.184641, "Destination");
  if (flag == 2) {
    map_marker_start(Start_lat, Start_long, Checkin);
  }
  //Initialize Google Play Services
  if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
        android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) ==
      PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
      //Location Permission already granted
      createLocationRequest();
      buildGoogleApiClient();
      mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    } else {
      //Request Location Permission
      checkLocationPermission();
    }
  } else {
    buildGoogleApiClient();
    mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
  }

}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {

  mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
    .build();
  mGoogleApiClient.connect();

}

protected void createLocationRequest() {
  mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
  mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000 * 10);
  mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000 * 5);
  mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

  startLocationUpdates();
}

protected void startLocationUpdates() {
  if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // TODO: Consider calling
    Toast.makeText(this, "LocationNotUpdated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(VisitTravel.this,
      new String[] {
        android.Manifest.permission
          .ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
      },
      20);

  } else {
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
      LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
        mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
      Log.d("Loc", "Location update started ..............: ");
      //       Toast.makeText(this, "LocationUpdatedStart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}


public void map_marker_start(Double lat, Double longt, String title) {
  MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
  LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, longt);
  Log.d("lat", String.valueOf(latLng.longitude));
  markerOptions.position(latLng);
  markerOptions.title(title);
  markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
  mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions).showInfoWindow();

}

public void map_marker_End(Double lat, Double longt, String title) {
  final MarkerOptions markerOptions_end = new MarkerOptions();
  LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, longt);
  Log.d("lat", String.valueOf(latLng.longitude));
  markerOptions_end.position(latLng);
  markerOptions_end.title(title);
  markerOptions_end.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
  mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions_end).showInfoWindow();
  mGoogleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
      String title = marker.getTitle();
      if (title.equals("Destination")) {
        dot_source.setText("\u2022");
        bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
        heading.setText("TEST");
        duration_textview.setText("Duration:" + " " + duration);
        return true;
      } else {
        bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
        return true;

      }

    }
  });

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
  mLastLocation = location;
  PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
  Log.d("location", mLastLocation.toString());
  LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
  obj.add(latLng);
  polylineOptions.addAll(obj);
  polylineOptions.width(9);
  polylineOptions.color(Color.parseColor("#2196f3"));
  mGoogleMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
  progressDialog.dismiss();
  mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
  CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
    latLng, 12);
  mGoogleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
}

public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;

private void checkLocationPermission() {
  if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(VisitTravel.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=
    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
        android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

      // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
      // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
      // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
      new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Location Permission Needed")
        .setMessage("This app needs the Location permission, please accept to use location functionality")
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(VisitTravel.this,
              new String[] {
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
              },
              MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
          }
        })
        .create()
        .show();


    } else {
      // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
      ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
        new String[] {
          android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        },
        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
    }
  }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
  String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
  switch (requestCode) {
    case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION:
      {
        // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
        if (grantResults.length > 0 &&
          grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

          // permission was granted, yay! Do the
          // location-related task you need to do.
          if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
              android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) ==
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
              buildGoogleApiClient();
            }
            createLocationRequest();
            ///  buildGoogleApiClient();
            //  Settingsapi();
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
          }

        } else {

          // permission denied, boo! Disable the
          // functionality that depends on this permission.
          Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return;
      }

      // other 'case' lines to check for other
      // permissions this app might request
  }
}



public String getKilometer(final double lat1, final double lon1, final double lat2, final double lon2) {
  Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      try {
        URL url = new URL("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" + lat1 + "," + lon1 + "&destination=" + lat2 + "," + lon2 + "&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=driving");
        final HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( in ));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
          buffer.append(inputLine + "\n");
        if (buffer.length() == 0) {
          // Stream was empty. No point in parsing.
          Log.e("empty", "empty");
        }
        JsonResponse = buffer.toString();
        Log.d("response", JsonResponse);
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(JsonResponse);
        JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes");
        JSONObject routes = array.getJSONObject(0);
        JSONArray legs = routes.getJSONArray("legs");
        JSONObject steps = legs.getJSONObject(0);
        JSONObject distance = steps.getJSONObject("distance");
        parsedDistance = distance.getString("text");


      } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  });
  thread.start();
  try {
    thread.join();
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return parsedDistance;
}



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  switch (requestCode) {
    // Check for the integer request code originally supplied to startResolutionForResult().
    case REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS:
      switch (resultCode) {
        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
          startLocationUpdates();
          break;
        case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
          Intent intent = new Intent(this, Incident.class);
          startActivity(intent);
          break;
      }
      break;
  }
}


@Override
protected void onStop() {
  super.onStop();
  if (wakeLock.isHeld()) {
    wakeLock.release();
  }

}




@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  super.onBackPressed();
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, IncidentView.class);
  if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
  }
  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
  setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
  finish();
}
}
```

Searched alot and not getting proper way to start with? Any help would really valuable.

--Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

Capture the latitude and longitude at regular intervals and store. Calculate and sum the distance between each stored value.